# Clear SELECT fields in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select

I'm using a function to set an entire sql query.
This function is used by other two to get the sql and then use it as they need.

Now, I want another function to execute the same query but I don't need all the fields that the previous functions needed. So, I want to know if there is a way to REPLACE the SELECT portion of the query after it's set.

Pseudocode:

```
function sql(){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('table');
}
function defaultSql(){
  $this->sql();
  $this->get();
}
function notAllFields(){
  $this->sql();
  // This is the solution I'm looking for. It should clear the select
  $this->db->clearSelect();
  // I define a different select
  $this->db->select('field');
  $this->get();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that I'm looking for a solution that actually CLEARS a select already set. My source code is much more complex than the sample so I don't want to pass any argument to the sql function. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can u try this way??

```
  function sql($fields = '*') {
    $this->db->select($fields);
    $this->db->from('table');
  }

  function defaultSql() {
    $this->sql();
    // ......
  }

  function notAllFields() {
    $this->sql('field');
    // .....
  }
```

Comment: Yes, this could be a way to achieve the same results, but it doesn't clear the select portion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of doing it like this

Assuming you are writing all these functions in model

```
function sql($status = false)
{
  if($status == true){
    $this->db->select('field');
  }else{
    $this->db->select('*');
  }
}

function get()
{
  $this->db->from('table');
}

function defaultSql(){
  $this->sql();
  $this->get();
}

function notAllFields(){
  $this->sql(true);
  $this->get();
}
```

Comment: Same than DBK. This is a way of getting the same result as by clearing the select portion, but it isn't what I was looking for.

Comment: @j4nSolo why are you even trying to clear the select portion after selecting. And why are you doing this when you can handle things with condition

Answer (score 0):

You can reset db-select by

```
1- <?php $this->db->clear_select(); ?>
```

which will reset all the query vars (select, where, join..from..etc).

2- in **application/library** extend database driver by creating **MY_DB_mysqli_driver.php** which should contains the following

```
<?php   defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_DB_mysqli_driver extends CI_DB_mysqli_driver
{
    public function __construct($param)
    {
        parent::__construct($param);
    }
    public function clear_select()
    {
        $this->qb_select = array();
    }
}
```

Then you can use **$this->db->select_clear()** function to clear only select portion.